# "width" constraint of UIImageView ignored when using "Aspect Fill" (Xcode, Auto-Layout)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout, storyboard

What I want to do is: On the right (see the image below) you see a slim bar (it's a UIView). It's pinned 100 to the top, 100 to the bottom and 10 to the right. That works fine.
[image: The constraints I set to the gray bar]

Then I added an UIImageView with some placeholder image of a mountain. I want it to be next to the gray bar. So I aligned the top, bottom and trailing to the gray bar and set a fixed width.

("view" is my gray bar)

[image: the constraints I set to the UIImageView]

Everything works fine. That's what it looks like in the storyboard and preview window:

[image: What it looks like in the storyboard and preview window]

It also looks the same in the simulator.
Now, I changed the UIImage to "Aspect Fill". Nothing changed in the preview. But now the app inside the simulator looks weird:

[image: What the app looks like with "Aspect Fill"]

I don't know why, but it is ignoring the width I set and it also doesn't align to the gray bar anymore.

What can I do?

Please tell me If you need more information. I'm not sure what is important :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `clipsToBounds` to `true` property of `UIImageView`.